# Android Spinner: Display items from a specific item position

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner filled of years (between 1800 and 2014), when a user click over this, it shows the 6 first years (between 1800 and 1806). I would like to display the years starting since the middle of my list (i.e. 1910).

Do you know how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using `spinner.setSelection(spinner.getCount()/2);`  hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I want the user selects the item by himself and not the list starting with this item selected. I mean, when the user clicks on the spinner, the first item displayed is 1900 (i.e), even if the list stars from 1800.  How can I do ?

Comment: try using `setOnTouchListener()` `spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            spinner.setSelection(spinner.getCount()/2);
            return true;
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

try this

int position = getIntent().getIntExtra( "name", defaultValue );
spinner.setSelection( position )